# asc and chr equivalent in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, chr

Well the title pretty much sums it up. I want to use something like asc("0") in C++, and want to make the program platform independent so don't want to use 48! Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" an answer that meets your needs!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use single-quotes to make a character constant:

```
char c = 'a';
```

The character type *is* a numeric type, so there is no real need for `asc` and `chr` equivalents.

Here's a small example that prints out the character values of a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char str[] ="Hello, World!";

  printf("string = \"%s\"\n", str);

  printf("chars = ");
  for (int i=0; str[i] != 0; i++) 
    printf("%d ", str[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
string = "Hello, World!"
chars = 72 101 108 108 111 44 32 87 111 114 108 100 33
```

Comment: oh right . absolutely! i dont know how i overlooked such a simple way, and i actually knew it all along, lol. thanks anyway!

Comment: yeah i guess i need a reputation of 15 to vote up! as soon as i do, ill be back here to vote up !

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, if you use a character enclosed by `''` and not `""` it means you are dealing with its raw binary value already.

Now, in C and C++, `"0"` is a literal two byte null-terminated string: `'0'` and `'\0'`. (ascii 48 ascii 0)

You can achieve what you want by using `var[0]` on a "" null-terminated string or use one of the conversion routines. (`atoi()` in C, `stringstream` lib in C++)

Comment: Also, seeing that you are new to the site, don't forget to upvote the answers that you find useful and accepting the one that is the most useful for you. Welcome!

Comment: i need a reputation of 15 to vote up! as soon as i do, ill be back here to vote up !

Answer (score 0):

You will get the ASCII value of a 0 character by writing: '0'.
Likewise 'char' for every char you need.