# Alternative to sprintf() to format the integer to an ascii character

Tags: c, printf

In my current program, I need to format an integer into an ASCII character. This will work with sprint() or snprintf().

Is there any alternative to sprintf() or snprintf() to format the data?

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: You want to format it into exactly one character? Will the integer be between 0 and 9?

Comment: @Thomas :I am writing an embedded program. Since usage of sprintf() will involve a large overhead. I need to avoid it.

Comment: @interjay : The integer can be a double digit number.

Comment: @PavanMunavalli Have a char array and add digit by digit

Comment: Does the library you are using have `itoa`?

Comment: @sirlark: I can use itoa(). But is formatting possible with itoa() ?

Comment: @Pavan what kind of formatting do you need, all itoa will give you is the integer as a decimal string

Comment: @sirlark: I need to display a decimal string as a character. For example if I have a decimal string of 65, I need to display as 'A'. But itoa() only helps me to convert an integer to a string.

Comment: What about `chr(atoi(decimal_str))`? Also you might want to edit your question to make the types involved a little more clear

Comment: `char ch = 65;` will give you `A` isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

```
char ch = (char)(i + (int)'0'); /* Where i is an integer */
```

This works for 0 to 9

Comment: the casting is unnecessary

Comment: @user3613500 Yes there will be implcicit conversions but just adds readability

Comment: The `(int)` cast is not needed.  `'0'` is an `int`.  No implicit conversion occurred.  The `(char)` cast is reasonable to quell warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any of `*printf()` functions, such as `printf, s(n)printf, fprintf` etc. `*print**f**` means "formatted printing". You might also try `printf("%c",(char)65)` but this might not help you very much. 
Built-in functions are in most cases faster than "self-written".

Answer (score 1):

The original question didn't make it clear that the input is a string containing an integer in decimal form, but reading the comments leads to a much lighter weight solution than sprintf

```
(char)(atoi(decimal_str))
```

Casting to `char` ensures the integer will be limited to 8 bits with the code of the same value. `atoi` converts a string of digits into an integer

Comment: Posted as an answer for future readers, so they don't have to dig through comments

Comment: In what library/include file did you find this function `chr()`? It's not in any of the standard libraries. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405137/asc-and-chr-equivalent-in-c-c.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's not standard. Confusion between turbo c and turbo pascal, in my foggy old memory. I've amended accordingly